# JavaScript function confusion?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand why does this code prints out a triangle.I wrote it,i don't know why the hell it works,and,how does it work

```
function makeLine(length) {
var line = "";
for (var j = 1; j <= length; j++) {
    line += "* ";
}
return line + "\n";

}


// your code goes here.  Make sure you call makeLine() in your own code.
function buildTriangle(width) {
var line = "";
for (i = 1 ; i <= width ; i++) {
    line += makeLine(i);
  }
return line;
}

console.log(buildTriangle(10));
```

Comment: `I wrote it` ..  are you kidding?

Comment: "**I wrote it**, *I don't know why the hell it works, and, how does it work*". Something about that doesn't add up...

Comment: Copy-pasting is not actually writing ... What did you expect it to "print" instead of the result you've got.

Answer (score 0):

`makeLine(length)` returns a line with a certain number of `*` (depending on the "length" passed as argument).

`buildTriangle(width)` calls the previous function several times passing numbers from 1 to whatever number you pass as "width" parameter (10 in your example).

Comment: If this doesn't make sense, you should go back to the basics and learn more about functions and "for" loops. And next time, maybe you'll have a more precise question than "I don't understand". Don't worry, we've all started somewhere.